# Cannot use yellow with Android Nougat notification's small icon

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I've a problem setting the notification small icon to yellow in Android 7.x

I'm using `notification.setColor(Color.YELLOW);` while building the notification object. It shows that olive(ish) color instead of yellow.

Also tried to use `notification.setColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,0));` but no luck, it shows the same olive(ish) color.

This is how it looks like in Android 7.x

[image: Android 7.1]

This is how it looks like in Android 6.x, which is the correct color

[image: Android 6.x]

Both images display the same notification with the same code base, but using different Android devices.

I'm using PushWoosh to send/receive push notifications, bellow is the exact code I'm using to create the notification object.

```
public class NotificationFactory extends AbsNotificationFactory {
@Override
public Notification onGenerateNotification(PushData pushData) {
    PushwooshUserdata pushwooshUserdata = GsonUtil.fromJson(pushData.getExtras().getString("u"), PushwooshUserdata.class);

    //create notification builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Header");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Message");

    //set small icon (usually app icon)
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    notificationBuilder.setColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,0));

    //set ticket text
    notificationBuilder.setTicker(getContentFromHtml(pushData.getTicker()));

    //display notification now
    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //build the notification
    final Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    //add sound
    addSound(notification, pushData.getSound());

    //add vibration
    addVibration(notification, pushData.getVibration());

    //make it cancelable
    addCancel(notification);

    //all done!
    return notification;
}

@Override
public void onPushReceived(PushData pushData) {
}

@Override
public void onPushHandle(Activity activity) {
}
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to describe a little bit more about how you are building your notifications

Comment: Thank you @Chisko, I updated the question to include the exact code I'm using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android is ensuring a minimum contrast ratio between the foreground color and background color.

With the yellow (#ffff35) foreground and a white background, the contrast ratio is only 1.07:1.

The olive foreground (#717d13) has the minimum contrast ratio of 4.5:1.

This is the relevant patch in the Android source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/4ff3b120ff8a788e3afeb266d18caf072f0b8ffb%5E%21/

I calculated the above contrast ratios using http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/.

Comment: Thank you @eric-fikus. That is the reason behind it.

Comment: I did some tests with colors that give contrast less than 4.5:1 with white, and it always ended getting a different color than the one I chose, and by calculating the new color's contrast it's always above 4.5.
You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to ensure that UI controls in a notification are also available in an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in your app, and you should always start that Activity when users click the notification. To do this, use the [setContentIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) method.

if you've defined color in colors.xml then in your NotificationBuilder add value as `.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.<YOUR_COLOR>))`

Source: [`NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int))