# Android N notification title and icon color is darker

Tags: android, android-notifications

When showing a notification in android N and O it shows like this
[image]

You can change the top color of the icon and the app name by using `setColor` method of the `NotificationCompat.Builder`, The problem is that the displayed color doesn't match the provided one as it gets **darker** in the notification.

I tested it on Google Pixel(Oreo). Is this documented somewhere? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Google decided to restrict acceptable colors in [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) when using [setColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor(int)). Yes, it's undocumented, unsolicited and [evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_be_evil)! After some digging (hacker's way) it may be found in the source code of (internal) [ContrastColorUtil](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/ContrastColorUtil.java). Inspect line [300 (`findContrastColor`)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/ContrastColorUtil.java#300) and [475 (`resolveContrastColor`)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/ContrastColorUtil.java#475) where the rationale is:

> Resolves a Notification's color such that it has enough contrast to be
> used as the color for the Notification's action and header text.

I do not agree. **Google should** have known better and **be doing no evil** to the **freedom** of aesthetic choices of **designers and developers**.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this now, or any document where it is stated that it will add enough contrast to given color

Comment: Still have the same problem. Any solution ?

Comment: The source code link is dead. Do you have any further info about this? I want to know what color can I use to satisfy the minimum contrast.

Comment: Found another answer with more info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917609

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I've update the post and fixed Web links to Google's Android source code, added direct links to referenced source code lines. The source code was refactored and the name changed from NotificationColorUtil to ContrastColorUtil...