# setColor small icon notification android

Tags: android, notifications

I change the top color of the icon and the app name by using setColor method of the NotificationCompat.Builder, The problem is that the displayed color doesn't match the provided one as it gets darker in the notification.
my color is #21bbe6
I did find out [Android N notification title and icon color is darker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590944/android-n-notification-title-and-icon-color-is-darker), but I still don't understand why, and how to deal with it. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmeyG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Google decided to restrict acceptable colors in Notification when using setColor.
It's undocumented!