# Where can I find the list of allowed colors for android notification icons?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, android-icons

It seems as if android doesn't except all colors.
When I set it to a certain green, the icon is green but different. Same goes if I try a certain red for example. It's like android sets it to the closest color out of a list of allowed colors.

Is there a list somewhere I can choose from?

I'm talking about the color of the icon on the top left.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question but I know why it happens. You can read the answer of @Nuno Henriques here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590944/android-n-notification-title-and-icon-color-is-darker

Answer (score 0):

for the notification icon color , first the icon should be in white color , all of it and then you can customize the color you want within your builder :

```
mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: It still doesn't use the green I've set. It uses a green color, but not the one I've specified. This is why I'm saying that it seems as if it "rounds" the color to the closest color out of a list of allowed ones. Like there are 20 colors or something to choose for or something like that. I'm not sure, but it definitely doesn't use the coloe I'm setting

Comment: Could you please write your desired color code and the setted color code here ? Because sometimeses color change from device to another due to the difference of screen technology